# how to use webkit in my iphone application to link javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, webkit

How do i use webkit in my application to link javascript?

My purpose is to call javascript function from my objective C code. I am reading that I need to have webkit embedded in my application to be able to do so. However I am unsure on how to use it from my application?

Comment: This is very unclear, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: my purpose is to call javascript function from my objective C code. I am reading that i need to have webkit embedded in my application to be able to do so. However i am unsure on how to use it from my application ? :)

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView has an instance method that handles this:

stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help

```
WebView* wview = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame: NSMakeRect( 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ) frameName: @"frame" groupName: @"group" ];

WebScriptObject* wso = [wview windowScriptObject ];
[wso evaluateWebScript: @"{YOUR SCRIPT CODE}"];
NSObject* proxyDefinition = [ wso callWebScriptMethod:
    @"YourMethod" withArguments: [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: "testarg",nil]];
```